# sending variable back to server in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to reload the same page with different content that varies depending on which link is clicked on the page. The url pattern for the page is `"/owners"`, which triggers the running of this method in `OwnerController.java`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/owners", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String processFindForm(Owner owner, BindingResult result, Map<String, Object> model) {
    Collection<Owner> results = this.clinicService.findOwnerByLastName("");
    model.put("selections", results);
    model.put("sel_owner",this.clinicService.findOwnerById(ownerId));//ownerId is not defined yet
    return "owners/ownersList";
}
```

The jsp includes a dynamically generated list of `ownerId` integer values, each of which can be used to send a unique `ownerId` back to the server.  What do I need to add to my jsp in order to get `ownerId` to have a user-specified value when `processFindForm()` is run?  In other words, what does the hyperlink need to look like?

Answer (score 0):

You are using **GET** request type.If you want to send any parameter to controller then you have to use either **@RequestParam** or **@PathParam** annotations based on requirement as an arguments to controller method. In  your case it will be something like...

```
public String processFindForm(@RequestParam("ownerID") String ownerId, BindingResult result, Map<String, Object> model) {... }
```

Take a look on this link as well: http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/spring-mvc-requestmapping-example

Comment: Thank you.  What about the other part of my question?  What do I need to add to the jsp so that each ownerId in the jsp can be clicked on by the user to send only that specific ownerId back to the server?